# Wordpress plugin disappeared after saving changes from editor

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have one Wordpress plugin that was working fine.
I tried to edit the code of one file of it from wordpress plugin editor, I saved changes to the file but there was a syntax error, so I edited the file again with the right syntax but while saving I got a strange error screen saying invalid header or something..

After that I went back to the wordpress dashboard to find the plugin disappeared.. the file syntax is 100% correct and I even tried to edit it back to its original code but still the plugin is disappearing

-I tried deactivating all the plugins.

-I tried to rename the folder of the disappearing plugin..
not sure what I have to do with that 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you check the file permissions on the plugin folder>

Comment: I didn't check it but there's no chance that the permission got changed while saving changes on a code .. do you think so ? @Difster

Answer (score 0):

First check is your plugin still visible in your plugin section then check if its active or not and if you did not find it there then try reinstalling the plugin. Hope this helps

Comment: -its not appearing in anywhere in the dashboard (installed plugins, toolbar)
-The plugin was made by a developer and I don't have it's source zip file

Comment: @Aproram Does the plugin still exists in the directory plugins?

Comment: @justkidding96 yes its still there, i tried renaming the folder of it.. same, nothing changed..

Comment: @Aproram try to disable all plugins through the database: `UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'a:0:{}' WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';` and try to enable debug mode in `wp-config.php`